# I'm graduating engineering program in only six semesters but have gotten no serious work experience along the way. How much will grad schools care?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, engineering, internship

I am a pet and Nat gas engineering student. I am graduating in six semesters (three yr) and this fall will be my fifth semester. I did not apply for an internship my freshmen year because I was under the impression no one hired freshmen. Therefore I assumed a rather standard summer job and figured I would certainly get one the next year. Now the oil and gas markets have completely crashed and there are almost zero internships right now. This was my last summer to find an internship before graduating and sending in graduate school applications. How much of a detriment will not having had any serious work experience be to my application?

I began college right out of high school. I have a 3.5 gpa and though I have not taken the GRE yet, I imagine I will perform 95+ percentile judging from my SAT and looking at a few problems.

I do not necessarily want to go to a top 20 graduate school for engineering, but I want to leave the door open because I am not quite sure what discipline I will be pursuing (but it will be some type of engineering or mathematical field). Do you think a six semester graduation in eng. (which judging from lack of online posts about it is almost unheard of) will be enough to be accepted into top 20 schools?

**One more question**: I have both a stock and Foreign Exchange account which I do profit from. I write backtests and apply statistical analysis to determine what to buy. I do not usually list these "jobs" on resumes or applications because I'd find that pretentious, but do you think I should include it in my graduate school application since I am lacking serious work experience?

EDIT: My question is not answered at all by the recommended question. I am seeking advice from ACADEMIA on this matter as I am not quite sure what to do. I am applying for a masters, not a PhD

Comment: Are you considered an engineer according to the laws of your country/your industry group? Or have you completed "PreEngineering" undergrad, and are now looking to take a Masters of Engineering?

Comment: I live in America. I will be an engineer "according to the laws of your [my] country" by the springtime. I will have already applied to graduate schools by then.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Looks like I can't answer this one, in my country things are substantially different (It is generally impossible to become an engineer in less than 4 years (normally 5:  3(UG)+2(PG)), and generally you are required to have an internship completed before you are allowed to graduate.) So I think my experience will not transfer.

Comment: May I ask what country that is?

Comment: In my case it is Australia, but it is pretty common I think. Take a look at the various definitions of Masters of Engineering in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Engineering

Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartered_Engineer_(UK)#International_equivalence  this is the notion of "according to ... your industry group"

It does vary a lot, for sure. see also http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1212/8513

(I actually don't have a masters, as I when I got my degree my uni just had a longer bachelors that is now considered as mostly equivalent, and had same requirements)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly)

Comment: My question is certainly a unique question. I know of no one else graduating in six semesters and this is what is causing my "problem".

Comment: In France, we are graduating from engineering school in 3 years = 6 semesters, but we do at least 10 months in company (4 in 2nd year, 6 in 3rd year), and it's an obligation to be graduated, dunno if that helps.

Comment: For starters, I suggest you have a chat with faculty at your school about what makes a strong graduate-studies application in your field. In my field (EE), unless you are pursuing studies which lean strongly towards industrial interests, I don't think lack of internship would be a show-stopper; whether this holds in petroleum/natural gas engineering I cannot say. (Also, I don't think the linked "possible duplicate" question really addresses OP's situation very well.)

Comment: I'm not aware of any accredited program in the US that would let you graduate with an engineering degree in only 6 semesters. I'm very curious about this.

Comment: If OP enrolled with a bunch of AP (advanced placement) credits, that could have cleared out a bunch of the usual "first year courses" and/or out-of-major requirements.

Comment: @user8001 I'd estimate 1-2% of engineering students at my university (that is, a few dozen students per year) graduate after only three years. A significantly larger fraction matriculate with sophomore standing (>30 hours) or even junior standing (>60 credit hours) because of AP credits. We are accredited out the wazoo.

Answer (score 6):

The lack of professional or industrial experience will likely not significantly influence graduate admissions committees, particularly if you're planning to apply outside of your undergraduate field. However, what **will** matter is that you don't mention any real research experience that you've acquired in any field, whether your own or another. When applying outside your "home" area, this will almost certainly raise alarm bells for committees, because they will have little solid ground to decide whether you will succeed in *their* program or not. (For instance, they may have a hard time deciding if you can successfully complete the coursework phase of their program, and they may not be able to tell if you will be able to become a competent researcher in that program, if research is part of the degree.)

Answer (score 1):

No, lack of work experience will not affect your application to graduate schools. Perhaps focusing on a research project or successfully completing a [Research Experience for Undergraduates funded by NSF summer program](http://www.nsf.gov/funding/pgm_summ.jsp?pims_id=5517&from=fund) will really help your future applications. In addition, I believe the Forex/Stock broker account may be worthwhile in mentioning IF you are going into finance (maybe quant) AND you were moderately successful at trading, or you developed some type of new algorithm in the field.

Comment: NSF also has fellowship programs that I *think* post-bacc "students" are eligible to apply for.